# How to add Core Data to existing Xcode 9 Swift 4 iOS 11 project?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

An update is requested, since this question has of course been answered for previous versions, the latest search result dated 12/16 generates irrelevant compatibility with previous iOS 9 and 10 projects.

The documentation of course says to select the Use Core Data checkbox when starting a new project, which I did not select, but now think iCloud + Core Data needs to be added to take my app to its next phase -> wherein something like NSFileCoordinator and NSFilePresenter is needed, since in my app UI users are presented with a number of TOPICS, each having three OPTIONS, regarding which users are to choose one option. For each topic the UI then displays the TOTAL NUMBER of users who have chosen each option and the PERCENTAGE of the total for each option.

Right now, the number of choices for each option and the percentage of the total are of course just calculated in my native app -> but actually need to be CALCULATED in something central like the cloud or most likely on a website…but then the website raises the simultaneous read/write problems that NSFileCoordinator and NSFilePresenter have already solved.

So if the iCloud + Core Data system can interject basic arithmetic calculations on the existing Ubiquitous Container numerical value totals - in the cloud upon receiving write numerical value commands from individual users - before sending out the new Ubiquitous Container numerical total and percent values - then I’d much appreciate advise on how fix the errors generated below in trying Create and Initialize the Core Data Stack. Otherwise guess I’ll have to scrape Xcode and go to a hybrid app like PhoneGap if that's the best one for the job.

Hence, referring to the Core Data Programming Guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1

and pasting in the following code in the beginning of my existing project, generates

> Use of unresolved identifier ‘persistentContainer’… ‘managedObjectContext’

... errors. And the line

```
init(completionClosure: @escaping () -> ()) {
```

... generates

> Initializers may only be declared within a type

```
import UIKit

import CoreData
class DataController: NSObject {
  var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
  init(completionClosure: @escaping () -> ()) {
    persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
    persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores() { (description, error) in
      if let error = error {
        fatalError("Failed to load Core Data stack: \(error)")
      }
      completionClosure()
    }
  }
}

init(completionClosure: @escaping () -> ()) {
  //This resource is the same name as your xcdatamodeld contained in your project
  guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DataModel", withExtension:"momd") else {
    fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
  }
  // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
  guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
    fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
  }

  let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)

  managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
  managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc

  let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background)
  queue.async {
    guard let docURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last else {
      fatalError("Unable to resolve document directory")
    }
    let storeURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("DataModel.sqlite")
    do {
      try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL, options: nil)
      //The callback block is expected to complete the User Interface and therefore should be presented back on the main queue so that the user interface does not need to be concerned with which queue this call is coming from.
      DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: completionClosure)
    } catch {
      fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
    }
  }
}

// followed by my existing working code:

class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

go to **File > new file...** select **core Data** under **iOS** and select **Data Model**
you'll still need some code which xcode auto generates whenever you select core data during project creation.
to get it, just create new project with core data option **checked** and copy all the code written under ** //Mark: - Core Data Stack** comment in **AppDelegate.swift** 
and add

```
import CoreData
```

above

**OPTIONAL**

And don't forget to change the name of the app after copying the completion block for **lazy var persistentContainer**.  Change the name of your app on this part *NSPersistentContainer(name: "SHOULD-BE-THE-NAME-OF-YOUR-APP") And managedObjectModel function of the code you just copied**

Comment: Ok thanks Jay. After "go to File > new file... select core Data under iOS and select Data Model" in my existing project I now have the file Model.xcdatamodel ... and then created a new project (not adding it to any existing project) and in AppDelegate.swift, class AppDelegate: ...{ right after my existing code, pasted the "// MARK: - Core Data stack ... // MARK: - Core Data Saving support" lines, inside the closing }. No precompile errors are showing yet, however I don't understand your OPTIONAL advice. I don't want to change the name of my app. Aren't I done with the temporary new project?

Comment: Alright, well my existing app builds, after creating a few Entities with Attributes, and runs ... without doing any of the OPTIONAL steps yet ... so I'll check this one green. Tanks!

Comment: For folks who come along later, you also probably want to add `self.saveContext()` in the applicationWillTerminate() and applicationDidEnterBackground() methods of AppDelegate.swift

Comment: ***change the name of the app*** means the model name in the `managedObjectModel` (or now the `persistentContainer` code). For example: `persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")`, where `DataModel` should be replaced with the name of your app, as that's the default name of the store that's created by Core Data. (Note: replace any spaces in the name with dashes, as in an app named `My App` would have a default store called `My-App`)

Comment: Why Xcode is so dumb that it cannot just add more functionality without additional steps from a developer side . Xcode is soo bad and I can say it because I used such idea as IntelliJ IDEA that is brilliant . Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 25):

If you're lazy like me, here's all the code you need to copy from the new Core Data project... (why make everyone create a new project?). Change YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE

At the top of your AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import CoreData
```

At the bottom of AppDelegate.swift file, before the ending curly bracket:

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so where to put this code in the existing project, I created the project and almost done now I am getting the message in console                                                Failed to load /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/Versions/A/CorePDF  I am thinking probably I need to enable core data in my app

Comment: Please put this code in AppDelegate.swift. Also add "import CoreData" to the top of AppDelegate.swift

Answer (score 4):

I know this is answered, but I believe the actual problem is with Apple's Documentation.  If you compare the Objective-C code to the Swift code, you will see that `var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext` is not actually defined.  You should replace that line with `var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer`.  This is the Objective-c interface

```
@interface MyDataController : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSPersistentContainer *persistentContainer; 
- (id)initWithCompletionBlock:(CallbackBlock)callback;
@end
```

So `DataController.swift` should be:

```
class DataController: NSObject {
 // Delete this line   var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer
    init(completionClosure: @escaping () -> ()) {
        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores() { (description, error) in
          if let error = error {
              fatalError("Failed to load Core Data stack: \(error)")
          }
          completionClosure()
       }
    }
}
```

As for the rest of your code, it's not necessary [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1).

> Prior to iOS 10 and macOS 10.12, the creation of the Core Data stack was more involved

That section of code is showing you the old way.

Comment: It's not about the docs. It's about the _template_ that you are given when you make a new project with Core Data checked.

Comment: The DataController class is not in the default template.  He got that from the docs I sourced.  If you check Core Data it adds all of your default Core Data code in the AppDelegate.  In the docs they mention how to factor it into it's own class, via the DataController.

Comment: Yep, 3 total steps: 1) [add the model file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48724602/1107226), 2) [set up the DataController class](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1), replacing the `managedObjectContext` with the `persistentContainer` as shown in this answer; then, 3) [add a property and call the DataController in the AppDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/IntegratingCoreData.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
lazy var persistantCoordinator :NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    
    let poc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel:managedObjectModel)
    
    let documentFolderUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in:.userDomainMask).last
    
    let path = documentFolderUrl!.appendingPathComponent("Database.sqlite")
    
    let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
    do{
        try poc.addPersistentStore(ofType:NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: path, options: options)
    }catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    return poc
}()


private lazy var managedObjectModel:NSManagedObjectModel = {
    
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"Database", withExtension:"momd")
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf:url!)!
}()


fileprivate lazy var managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext = {
    
    let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistantCoordinator
    
    return moc
}()
```